# URL RewriteRule on CodeIgniter .htacces

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have the follow URL:

```
http://<site>/assets-teste/...
```

And I want to rewrite it to:

```
http://<site>/application/views/ambiente_teste/assets-teste/...
```

I've tryed the following on my `.htaccess`:

```
ReweiteRule ^assets-teste/?$ /application/views/ambiente_teste/assets-teste [NC,L]
```

Comment: So you want to rewrite it to `/assets-teste/application/views/ambiente_teste/` ? Or do you want to remove `/application/views/ambiente_teste/` completely?

Comment: Hey kkkk. Exactly, I want to rewrite `/application/views/ambiente_teste/assets-teste/` to simple `/assets-teste/`.
Or just remove `/application/views/ambiente_teste/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you (me) should use underline `_` character as space instead of `-`.

The first part of the `RewriteRule` says what you want to rewrite when found in the URL.

Localizing in the URL:

```
^\/assets-teste\/(.*)
```

Writing the new url:

```
/application/views/ambiente_teste/assets-teste/$1
```

And the .htaccess will look like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^\/assets-teste\/(.*) /application/views/ambiente_teste/assets-teste/$1 [L]
```

---

**Additional explanation:**

Rewrite engine will be enabled:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Base directory for rewrite will be /:

```
RewriteBase /
```

If request match a not existing file, continue:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

If request match a not existing directory, continue:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

`[L]` Stop the rewriting process immediately and don't apply any more rules.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're using CodeIgniter. They have routing built into their system, I suggest using that to change your URL schemes.

[CodeIgniter URI Routing](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: Oh, this is true, but I don't understand how to use the routes.php to do add a direct route to this folder, so can you help me?

Comment: Under applicaiton/config/routes.php, add the following:

`$route['assets-teste/'] = 'controller_name/method';`

Basically, you're taking the $route array, and adding in a key that is used as the URI you want, then the value is set to the method that is used to render that page.

Here's a good video on routing in CI: [CodeIgniter Routing: YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7yuztPZWU4)